# Jetpack Navigation Animation Complete Listener

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm trying to get a callback, using the Jetpack Navigation library, when a new navigation event is **completed** in order to change the status bar color.

So far I've found
`navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener`
which notifies me when a new navigation *starts* but not when it *completes*, meaning that the enter/exit transitions have completed.

Is there any method to know when all navigation transitions have completed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
navHostFragment?.childFragmentManager?.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
    val currentFragment = navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.fragments.firstOrNull()
    if (currentFragment is YourFragment) {
        // your code here  
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60867969/4862911) to achieve it. briefly, as a work around, you can add some delay to your **animation** when transaction is started.

**as mentioned in the answer; fragment replacement is starting when you click to "navigate to X fragment" button. so the delay is only in fragment transaction animation not in replacement**

add delay to animation by adding `android:startOffset="300"` in your_anim_name.xml file on your **anim** folder which is under res folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:ordering="together">
<alpha
    android:startOffset="300"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="400"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    />
<translate
    android:startOffset="300"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="400"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple as an "abc":
For doing some job after transition ends, add a listener on a `Fragment.View`

For example, if we need to jump to another `Destination` only after current `Fragment` is drawn and presented on the screen, just place this hook in onResume callback:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    view?.animation?.setAnimationListener(object: Animation.AnimationListener {
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {}
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {}
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
            // Do the navigation or whatever you want
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem and finally found a workaround.

The idea is that when the exit animation of the current fragment ends, `onDestroyView` of that fragment is called.

So as long as the duration of the enter and exit animations are the same, we can use this method as a callback.

```
class BaseFragment() {
    private var leavingDestination = false

    fun navigateNext() {
        leavingDestination = true
        findNavController().navigate(blaBlaBla)
    }

    fun onNavigationAnimationEnds() {
        TODO()
    }

    // We just need to add an extra check, to be sure that onNavigationAnimationEnds is not called on configuration change
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        if(leavingDestination) {
            onNavigationAnimationEnds()
            leavingDestination = false
        }
    }
}
```

I use the described approach to call some code in the back/exiting fragment. If you need a callback in the fragment you navigate to, you can just use shared `ViewModel`. Like the [ActivityViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) or [NavGraph scoped ViewModel](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-with-saved-state-jetpack-navigation-data-binding-and-coroutines-df476b78144e).

Something like this:

```
class FragmentA() {
    private val mainActivityViewModel by activityViewModels<MainActivityViewModel> { viewModelFactory }
    ...
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        if(leavingDestination) {
            mainActivityViewModel.onNavigationAnimationEnds()
            leavingDestination = false
        }
    }
}
...
class MainActivity() {
    private val _navigationAnimationEndsEvent = MutableLiveData(Event())
    val navigationAnimationEndsEvent: LiveData<Event>; get() = _navigationAnimationEndsEvent

    fun onNavigationAnimationEnds() {
        _navigationAnimationEndsEvent.value = Event()
    }
}
...
class FragmentB() {
    private val mainActivityViewModel by activityViewModels<MainActivityViewModel> { viewModelFactory }

    override fun onActivityCreated() {
        ...
        mainActivityViewModel.navigationAnimationEndsEvent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let {
                onNavigationAnimationsEnds()
            }    
        })
    }

    private fun onNavigationAnimationEnds() {
        TODO()
    }    
}
```

Event class I used:

```
open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

    var hasBeenHandled = false; private set

    fun getContentIfNotHandled() = if (hasBeenHandled) null else {
        hasBeenHandled = true
        content
    }

    fun peekContent(): T = content
}
```

P.S.: I tried overriding onCreateAnimation/onCreateAnimator functions and add listeners to them, but they were never called.

Comment: i am sorry but this is really very bad approach.