# Android navigation animation complete listener

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, android-jetpack

I am using architecture components ( jetpack-navigation) and I have definied default animations for navigation for EnterAnim, ExitAnim, PopEnterAnim and PopExitAnim. When I am navigating from one fragment to another Fragment Navigation animation is launched and simultaneously is invoked httpRequest + obsering data what causes big performance issue - navigation animation + rendering view from fetched data.
I would like to add listener which will help me to find a point when animation is completed and I can start observing data (rednering view). Does anyone had simmilar case?
Here it is simmilar case [Jetpack Navigation Animation Complete Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57091805/jetpack-navigation-animation-complete-listener)
 but id does not resolve problem...